# Check changes before routing in React / Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

I am having a Next JS app where there are very simple two pages.

-> **Home page**

```
import Header from "../components/header";

const handleForm = () => {
  console.log("trigger");
};

export default () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <form onSubmit={handleForm}>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
      <button type="submit"> Login </button>
    </form>
  </>
);
```

-> **About page**

```
import Header from "../components/header";
export default () => (
  <>
    <Header />
    <h1>About us</h1>
  </>
);
```

**Requirement:**

-> Home page has a login form

-> If user started typing in any of the fields then without submitting the form, if he tries to move to `About us` page then a warning needs to be displayed something similar like [beforeunload_event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event).

I am not sure how we can handle it in react as I am new to it.. Kindly please help me to handle a alert if user trying to navigate to other url while editing the form fields..

[image: Edit react-spring-nextjs-routes (forked)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you can achieve your goal by listen the event `routeChangeStart` as then throws exception in case of rejecting to move the target url.

I forked above codesandbox and created a simple demo based on your idea which doesn't allow to switch page in case of username having value (form is dirty).

Here is the general idea:

```js
import router from "next/router";

export default () => {
  // Assume this value holds the status of your form
  const [dirty, setDirty] = React.useState();

  // We need to ref to it then we can access to it properly in callback properly
  const ref = React.useRef(dirty);
  ref.current = dirty;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // We listen to this event to determine whether to redirect or not
    router.events.on("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);

    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeStart", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleRouteChange = (url) => {
    console.log("App is changing to: ", url, ref.current);
    
    // In this case we don't allow to go target path like this
    // we can show modal to tell user here as well
    if (ref.current) {
      throw Error("stop redirect since form is dirty");
    }
  };

  return (
    // ...
  )

}
```

The link codesandbox is here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-nextjs-routes-forked-sq7uj

Comment: Thanks for your solution.. And I am happy you have modified my code with needed functionalities.. One important thing I would like to know from here is that whether it is possible to check form dirty intead of each input fields? Because in my real app I have 50 input fields and if any of the 1 out 50 inputs is changed then that needs to be considered as dirty..

Comment: In most cases checking form dirty is always a good way to go for ;) you could use some lib which deals with form pretty well like Formik

Comment: You have assigned to ```Username``` input alone, but if I want to implement in my app, then I need to copy paste the same code for all 50 fields.. So is there a way to check if a form is dirty? If so feel free to modify the solution..

Comment: Do you know about `Formik` which offers outstanding features as working with form. It helps you to detect a form dirty or not with ease

Comment: Sorry I am not supposed to use any external form libraries.. I am in the need to achieve it  in normal form way..

Comment: If so, you might have to do the same thing as a lib does to check things own your own.

Comment: Okay, As I said in question also that I am new to react and hence struggling with achieving this solution.. Your help would be beneficial for me if you modify the solution with form dirty.. I am just requesting you..  Your help would help me to understand the things better.. Thanks..

Comment: No worries. If your form is just input tag only, it’s pretty simple too check a form is dirty. I would leave you another hint regarding to that as I’m free

Comment: Yes form is input tags only and it will contain text, radio, checkbox, textarea kind of inputs.. Hoping for your updated solution on it..

Comment: I've just dropped you an idea how to implement checking a form is dirty or not https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-nextjs-routes-forked-sq7uj?file=/pages/index.js